# How do I change the "This field is required" validation message Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, formvalidation-plugin, jquery-form-validator

i'm trying to customize the error messages that pop up when a form field isn't valid, however, all that is showing up is "This field is required", but i included a messages block in my code to write my own messages. Could anyone tell me how to fix this?
This is my code:

````
      rules: {
          fullname: {
              required: true,
          }
      },
      messages: {
          fullname: {
              required: "Please enter your full name",
          },
          
      }, 
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
 }); ```
````

Comment: remove the "required" attribute from the form field or the "required: true"

Comment: Your code appears to work fine as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tpsz7kmb/. Can you please add a snippet to the question showing a working demonstration of this behaviour.